# RabbitMQ: using Routing to achieve message selection

Tags: c#, queue, rabbitmq

I'm trying to implement a solution using RabbitMQ to achieve something like distributed RPC using only one request and one response queue for a high number of processors, I've already implemented such a solution with Apache Apollo and I would have liked to be able to migrate it to RabbitMQ. Here are the key points:

- Each servers connects to the request queue
- Each server processes only requests that are supposed to be for him (header field)

In my implementation for Apollo the key point was the use of selectors (like where clauses on values of header fields), I thought this is achieved in RabbitMQ through Routing and routing key, but I must be wrong because I see workers receiving messages that are not supposed to be for them.

I have modified the Routing sample (http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-dotnet.html) in order to replicate the problem, I have two consumers that I can start with different parameters defining the routingKey, and a producer that generated messages for one of the consumers. The behavior I see is that the consumption of messages seems to be random (message for 'John' is processed by consumer for 'John' the first time and by consumer for 'Mary' the second time)

Does anybody have any indication or code snippets on using selectors in RabbitMQ?

Below my code for the consumer:

```
public static void Main( String[] args )
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
    using ( var connection = factory.CreateConnection() )
        using ( var channel = connection.CreateModel() )
        {
            const String request = "request";
            channel.ExchangeDeclare( request, "direct" );

            channel.QueueDeclare( request, true, false, false, null );

            if ( args.Length < 1 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( " Press [enter] to exit." );
                Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.ExitCode = 1;
                return;
            }

            var myRoutingKey = args[0];
            channel.QueueBind( request, request, myRoutingKey );

            Console.WriteLine( $" [*] Waiting for messages for {myRoutingKey}." );

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer( channel );
            consumer.Received += ( model, ea ) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( body );
                var routingKey = ea.RoutingKey;
                Console.WriteLine( $" [x] Received '{routingKey}':'{message}'" );
            };
            channel.BasicConsume( request, true, consumer );

            Console.WriteLine( " Press [enter] to exit." );
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

and for the producer:

```
public static void Main( String[] args )
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
    using ( var connection = factory.CreateConnection() )
        using ( var channel = connection.CreateModel() )
        {
            const String request = "request";
            channel.ExchangeDeclare( request, "direct" );

            channel.QueueDeclare( request, true, false, false, null );

            var routingKey = args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : "John";

            const String message = "Hi";
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( message );
            channel.BasicPublish( request, routingKey, null, body );
            Console.WriteLine( $" [x] Sent '{routingKey}':'{message}'" );
        }

    Console.WriteLine( " Press [enter] to exit." );
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess why this wasn't working for you. The key is these two lines in your consumer.

```
channel.QueueDeclare( request, true, false, false, null );
channel.QueueBind( request, request, myRoutingKey );
```

And the fact that "request" is the name of your queue for "all" of your consumers. If you run this program setting multiple bindings using multiple routing keys the end result is that the queue named "request" is bound to your exchange with multiple routing keys (e.g. "John","Mary"). Remember that when you do this binding, the binding is not transient in the RabbitMQ server and they stick around.

Now back to how to solve your problem. There are multiple options but here is one of them. First I recommend reading the [RabbitMQ Model](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html).

You can use the same tutorial code which has these lines instead of yours:

```
 var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
 channel.QueueBind( queueName, request, myRoutingKey );
```

But the above means every time you run your consumer program a new queue is created and bound to the exchange with your desired routing key. The alternative is to use the same code you did before but just choose your queue name appropriately instead of a fixed queue name. For instance, you can have one queue per routing key

```
var queueName = myRoutingKey ;
channel.QueueDeclare( queueName, true, false, false, null );
channel.QueueBind( queueName, request, myRoutingKey );
```

Or alternatively you can group a number of routing keys into a single queue similar to the tutorial sample.

The point is what you need to do can't be done with one queue. (Other than you filtering out messages when you consume them). But that didn't sound like a real requirement for you. What you asked is that each consumer server only deals with its relevant messages which you can do in this model. The producers only publish to that one exchange though (which is what you wanted).

Comment: Hi Amin, thanks for your answer. I have also found that using dynamically generated queues the problem wouldn't arise. Anyway I was looking for a solution with only a request and a response queue both because of performance concerns and because the other solution I had implemented before with another broker was of that kind. Having recognized a different model the latter is not a problem, just requires some redesign, but I definitely need to verify the performances.

Comment: Moreover by using dynamically generated queues I loose all messages from the producers that are generated whilst the routing consumers are not running. I've also tried to declare the exchanges as durable but it doesn't help.

Comment: Dynamically generated queues would essentially be temporary queues for you since you are going to lose the name of the queue I assume? I don't believe dynamic queue names is going to be a solution for you just use consistent names (think of them as your selectors really). There is no performance hit for doing it this way. This is what RabbitMQ is designed for.